# assembly: continuing after call

Tags: assembly, call

I'm looking at the following code:

```
cmp edx edx
jle loc_40234
call some_func
add eax, eax
```

What I'm trying to understand is how can I even reach the fourth line since it's not a loc (can't be jumped to) and it immediately follows a function call. I mean, the call acts like a jump right?

Edit: ok I understand the basic idea. I should have specified: this code is part of some_func (it's a loop I gather).

Comment: If code inside `some_func` does `call some_func`, then that forms up logical pattern known as "recursion". The CPU doesn't care any way, not aware of func/procedure concepts, it just jumps around instructions as instructed, and if the recursion is too deep, the stack will overflow from the stored return-addresses (one more added by each `call`).

Comment: Ok got it, thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmp edx,edx` will compare `edx` with itself, so it will always be "equal", and `jle` is always taken.

The `call` will be not reached from this code path (if it will ever execute, some other code would have to jump directly at the `call` instruction or at the `jle` instruction with flags already set to evaluate as "greater" condition).

The `call` is technically like `jmp`, with small additional twist. It will push to stack address of next instruction (`add`), so if the code at `some_func` will somehow use this address from stack to jump there (most commonly functions end with `ret` instruction, which does exactly that, pops top of stack value and jumps to it, which is the return address, if the stack content was not damaged and stack pointer is correct), the `add` will be reached.

Of course it's impossible to say without checking `some_func` code, if it will return to that `add`.